# Solve the following system of non-linear equations: $x^2+4xy+y^2=13$, $2x^2+3xy=8$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system of non-linear equations:   $$\begin{align}x^2+4xy+y^2&=13\\   2x^2+3xy&=8.\end{align}$$

I started off this problem by rearranging and substituting but I’m stuck. I think that I have to change this system to a simple equation in one variable, but I don't know how to do it, please help me.

Comment: Please show your efforts to rearrange and substitute.

Comment: $y$ can easily be made the subject of the second equation.

Comment: I notice that $y$ occurs only once, and to the first power, in the second equation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of $13$ and $8$ by multiplying the first equation by $-8$ and the second one by $13$.  Add both.  Factorizing gives $(9x+8y)(2x-y)=0$.

Comment: coolest solution.  gut gemacht! +1 :-)

Comment: Also for me +1.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael Hoppe stated in his answer, if we multiply the first equation by $−8$ and the second one by $13$, we can add the two equations and factor to get $(9x+8y)(2x-y) = 0$. We now have that $$2x = y$$ $$\text{or}$$ $$9x = -8y.$$

Quick side note: When you can't go any further try multiplying each equation by a certain number so that when you add or subtract, you cancel out the constant. Then you have a chance of factoring.

Plugging into the second equation gets us $2x^2+6x^2 = 8$, so $8x^2 = 8$ and $x = \pm 1$. Substituting each again into the second equation gets us two solution pairs, $(1, 2)$ and $(-1, -2)$.

Now we plug in $y = -\frac{9}{8}x$ and get $2x^2-\frac{27}{8}x^2 = 8$, so $-\frac{11}{8}x^2 = 8$. $x^2 = -\frac{64}{11}$, so $x = \pm i\cdot \frac{8}{\sqrt{11}}$. We get two more solution pairs, $(\frac{8i}{\sqrt{11}}, -\frac{9i}{\sqrt{11}})$ and $(-\frac{8i}{\sqrt{11}}, \frac{9i}{\sqrt{11}})$. (Of course, you can rationalize the denominator on your own.)

Final answer: $(1, 2), (-1, -2), (\frac{8i}{\sqrt{11}}, -\frac{9i}{\sqrt{11}}), (-\frac{8i}{\sqrt{11}}, \frac{9i}{\sqrt{11}})$.

-FruDe

Comment: I have used a classic method +1.

Comment: I am grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$y=\frac{8-2x^2}{3x},\quad x\neq 0 \tag 1$$

for the second equation. After substitute into first equation $$x^2+4xy+y^2=13$$ this value of $y$ you will found these solutions:

$$x=i\frac{8\sqrt{11}}{11},\:x=-i\frac{8\sqrt{11}}{11},\:x=1,\:x=-1$$
Take these solutions and substitute them on $2x^2+3xy=8$ to find the $y$ values.

Comment: Nice approach, Merci!